# loading data from file into 2d array

Tags: perl, arrays, io, multidimensional-array

I am just starting with perl and would like some help with arrays please.
I am reading lines from a data file and splitting the line into fields:

```
open (INFILE, $infile);
do {
my $linedata = <INFILE>;
my @data= split ',',$linedata;
....
} until eof;
```

I then want to store the individual field values (in @data) in and array so that the array looks like the input data file ie, the first "row" of the array contains the first line of data from `INFILE` etc.

Each line of data from the infile contains 4 values, x,y,z and w  and once the data are all in the array, I have to pass the array into another program which reads the x,y,z,w and displays the w value on a screen at the point determined by the x,y,z value. I can not pas the data to the other program on a row-by-row basis as the program expects the data to in a 2d matrtix format.
Any help greatly appreciated.
Chris

Answer (score 6):

That's not really that difficult, you just need to store the splits, not in their own separate list, but in an array, taking up a slot of a larger array:

```
my @all_data;

while (my $linedata = <INFILE>) { 
   push # creates the next (n) slot(s) in an array
       @all_data
     , [ split ',',$linedata ] 
       # ^ we're pushing an *array* not just additional elements.
      ; 
}
```

However, if you're just trying to read a commonly-known concept as a *comma-separated values format*, then have a look at something like [`Text::CSV`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text::CSV), because the full capabilities of CSV is more than splitting on commas.

Comment: These solutions work well but the problem I now have is how do I get the actual values out of the array? eg if the input file is 1,2,3,4
5,6,7,8

I want to te be able to pass those values to another program from the array

Thanks
chris

Comment: To give a litle more detail, the code that reads the data is 


RunMenu(
    "FILES_ASCII_READ",
    "abort",
    sub {
        PanelResults(
            "spec_choice",
            "data_file"      => $csvfile,
....

$csfile is the text file containing the data 
1,2,3,4

5,6,7,8....

and this is read in ok.
I would like to substiute the data array for $csvfile